# Free memory on server only goes down until it runs out

Tags: magento2, memory

When I visit my website the free memory on my sever goes down. Of course this is supposed to happen. Then I refresh the page and check the free memory again. It goes further down. If I refresh the page 10 more times my memory is low. Why does the RAM on my server keep going down with every page visit? Shouldn't the older page loads finish and the RAM go back up after the page is done loading?

Comment: Can you give us your server info?

Comment: AWS EC2 instance T2.Large 8 MB RAM